# What is canonical momentum in rigid body systems?

Tags: classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets

What is the canonical momentum in rigid body systems? It appears to me that it can't be the angular momentum as these have non-vanishing Poisson brackets, but any canonical coordinates have $\left\{p_i,p_j\right\}=0$.

If I'm right, what is the relation between canonical momentum and angular momentum?

Comment: Well, that's just different Poisson structures.

Comment: I think you will have to consider two new Hamiltonian variables $\theta_i$ and $l_i$ and the Poisson brackets should be written in terms of these variables. Here $l_i$ will be the canonical momentum $\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}$.

Comment: @Qmechanic, not sure what you mean. Can you address my argument?

Answer (score 1):

The rigid body, though Hamiltonian, is not a symplectic dynamical system, hence does not follow the same pattern as textbook mechanics. Instead it is described by a Lie-Poisson bracket with nontrivial Casimirs. These are functions with zero Poissson bracket with everything, hence constants of the motion. In general, fixing an independent set of Casimirs at a fixed value produces a foliation of the Poisson manifold into symplectic leaves. This is discussed in detail in the Book *Mechanics and symmetry* by Marsden and Ratiu.